# iOS - Different MOCs and managed objects status

Tags: core-data, ios6, restkit-0.20

in the context of some tests I'm writing I've found the following issue. I make use of RestKit 0.20.2, among the other natural purposes, also to manage my coredata-related aspects.

In one of those tests, I create a CoreData entity A, containing a Date as one of its fields, by assigning it a Nil value (it's an optional field). My saving function performs the following code:

```
NSError* myError;
[[RKTestFactory managedObjectStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&myError];
NSLog(@"Save done on main queue with myError: %@", myError); 
NSAssert1(myError == Nil, @"Coredata saving error: %@", myError);
```

After this save, an algorithm is run which operates on A and update that date field. This algorithm works in a private managed object context:

```
// Get a Local Managed Object Context
NSManagedObjectContext* myLocalMOC = [[DDRestKitManager sharedInstance].objectManager.managedObjectStore  newChildManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType trackChanges:YES];
```

(DDRestKitManager is a singleton managing about every RestKit-related aspect of my project). This algorithm first retrieves A with a FetchRequest within its private managed object context, then operates on it and finally updates its date field. It then saves every CoreData related aspect it dealt with (including the updated A-status) with a save on its private MOC.

When, in the previous test body, I need to invoke the very same algorithm again on the very same entity A after having updated some of its fields in order to test the new algorithm outcome, I need to put A's date field back to Nil before invoking the algorithm. This is what I do:

```
A.date_field = Nil;
[[TestCoreDataManager sharedInstance] save];  
// <invoke_algorithm>
```

(TestCoreDataManager is a further singleton providing objects and saving them by means of the previously reported function). The problem is that when the algorithm retrieves again the object, the date_field is not Nil but still contains the previously assigned value.

It seems like the instance of A retrieved by the algorithm in its private context is not up-to-date wrt the underlying persistent store. Is there anyone who might tell me what I'm doing wrong?

---

Some more details

I've just moved the default semantics of this date field in order to be always not nil and to have 0 as default value. I rewrote the algorithm in order for the test condition to be `[A.date_field timeIntervalSince1970] == 0` in place of `A.date_field == Nil`.

In my code, in order for that test to be met, I use the following code

```
A.date_field = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
[TestCoreDataManager save]; // [mainManagedObjectContext saveOnPersistentStore:&myError];

// Get a Local Managed Object Context
NSManagedObjectContext* myLocalMOC =
[[DDRestKitManager sharedInstance].objectManager.managedObjectStore
 newChildManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType
 tracksChanges:YES];

<query_for_A_entities_in_the_store>;
```

At this point `A.date_field` contains the value it had before resetting to 0 seconds from 1970.

The even more strange part follows. If I replace

```
A.date_field = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
```

with

```
A.date_field = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1];
```

or

```
A.date_field = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:-1];
```

and leave the rest of the code untouched, then the child managed object context fetch an A object with the date_field now up-to-date to the correct date and time (1970, 1:00:01 a.m. or 0:59:59 a.m. respectively).

This is driving me crazy.

Comment: When doing things like `saveToPersistentStore` you should not be testing the error for `nil` as that isn't guaranteed to be true. Instead you should be getting and testing the BOOL that is returned from the method.

Comment: This seems not to be the case as I expected. Documentation says that in case of any errors, the error would be set to the reason triggering this error, but it's always at Nil. Anyway, I've just tried to test against `saveToPersistentStore:` return value and it's always `YES`.

Comment: I've also experienced this issue on iOS 12+, any updates here?